# XmlPullParserException when calling nextTag() for the first time in Android application

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I'm writing an Android application that parses an XML feed using XmlPullParser.

This is the XML I'm attempting to parse:

http://www.corvallistransit.com/rtt/public/utility/file.aspx?contenttype=SQLXML&Name=RoutePattern.rxml

This is the code where it's blowing up:

```
public List parseRouteInfo(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);

        // This is the line
        parser.nextTag();

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "RoutePattern");
        return readPatterns(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

And this is the exception thrown:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@416d80a8)
```

To have the system accept the URL, I'm changing the `&` character in the URL parameter to be `&amp;` but aside from that I'm following the [Android XML Parsing Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) as closely as possible.

I understand why an exception is thrown (no `START_TAG` or `END_TAG` found), but I can't figure out why the parser is at `END_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: Are you certain that you need to change the ampersand? It looks like the input stream is pointing to an empty document.

Comment: Seems that's what the problem was.  I'm not sure why it wasn't accepting the URL at first, but this specific issue regarding `END_DOCUMENT` isn't a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the culprit:

> To have the system accept the URL, I'm changing the `&` character in the URL parameter to be `&amp`;

For some reason the system wasn't accepting a URL without that change, but it seems to be fine now.